# getDefaultViewMode in magento2 returns null

Tags: magento2

Why am i getting Call to a member function `getDefaultViewMode()` on null in `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x\magento2\app\code\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php on line 409` when I create a custom block and try to extend it from core.

**In File:** `vendor/module/Model/Engine.php`

```
namespace Tagalys\Tglssearch\Model;

class Engine extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel  {
private function _makeTagalysRequest()
{

  $current_list_mode = $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar')->getCurrentMode();

}
```

`getCurrentMode()` which is from `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php`  says

```
$mode = $this->_getData('_current_grid_mode');

    if ($mode) {
        return $mode;
    }

    $defaultMode =    this->_productListHelper->getDefaultViewMode($this->getModes());
```

**In Core File:** `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList.php`

```
public function getDefaultViewMode($options = [])
{
    echo 'helper';die;
    print_r($options);die;
    if (empty($options)) {
        $options = $this->getAvailableViewMode();
    }
    return current(array_keys($options));
}
```

Why am i getting  **Call to a member function getDefaultViewMode() on null** error ?

Comment: Please edit your original question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121810/getdefaultviewmode-returning-null-magento-2 instead of creating a new one

Comment: i have deleted the first one